# Possibility to store a duration/time in a mysql datetime field

Tags: mysql, datetime, time

I have a field that for various reasons, need to accept a variety of date/time inputs. While I can use a `DATETIME` type to store both a date and datetime, for example:

- `2014-01-01 00:00:00` (a date)
- `2014-01-01 01:20:23` (a datetime)

I'm unable to figure out how to store a time. Would it be possible in any way, or would I need to store some sort of hack-value that would be used for parsing in the application, such as:

- `0000-01-01 05:00:00` (parse as `05:00:00` --> time)

Or, is there a better way to store this?

For example, how I'm currently doing the sql is as follows:

```
select if(vd=date(vd), date(vd), 
       if(date(vd)='0000-01-01', right(vd,8), 
       vd)) formatted_vd, vd from spread

formatted_vd    vd
2014-01-01      2014-01-01 00:00:00
2014-01-01      01:12:23    2014-01-01 01:12:23
05:00:00        0000-01-01 05:00:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While MySQL does actually [have a TIME type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html), most of the time (no pun intended), you would not want to use it.  Instead, using `DATETIME` is usually the better choice.

That being said, if you have a `DATETIME` value, and for some reason you want to isolate the time component, MySQL offers a `TIME()` function which can extract the time by itself.

Comment: thanks for this answer. My question then, is how would I know that the item is a time if I'm storing it as a `datetime` field?

Comment: Well, if you really have no need for the date component, then in theory using `TIME` would be OK.  But, if you are using `DATETIME`, then just ignore the date component if you only care about time.

Comment: it's a bit of a "mixed-type" thing (unfortunately from a db perspective...). Where the field can have all three of times, datetimes, and dates.

Comment: Then I suggest using `datetime` and perhaps using another column if you need to keep track of to what that value actually corresponds.  This seems like a database design problem now, rather than a limitation of the types which MySQL offers.